# Parameter list for functions(taking different parameters) implementing same Abstract method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one abstract method in Class SamplePArent

```
Class SampleParent
 @abc.abstractmethod
 def getData(Self, **kwargs)
```

It is being implemented in 3 different child classes (A, B and C). And in all the three child classes, getData method takes different parameters.

What will be the parameter list of getData method in parent class as well as all the 3 child classes so that the concept of abstraction is preserved.

```
Class A
 def getData(self,null) # takes no parameter

Class B
 def getData(self, count) # takes integer value as a parameter

Class C
 def getData(self, name_dict) # takes dictionary as a parameter
```

Is the argument list for all the function definition correct. I have given **kwargs in parent method, because all of its 3 implementation method are taking different types of parameter or no parameter.

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Since, all the 3 implementation of abstract method are taking different parameters. What will be the parameter(or argument list) of abstract function itself in the parent , say def getData(self, **kwargs). And if i use **kwargs, how will the argument list of 3 implemented methods look like?

Comment: It would be helpful to stop thinking of Python like a statically typed language